# Highcharts Column Chart number LOW but column looks HIGH

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm leveraging [angular2-highcharts](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) to illustrate a daily score from 0 to 100. I'm having an issue with the way Highcharts automagically illustrates a column when only one data point is present in a [series](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column).

[image: Highcharts Column Chart]

Technically, this is correct. However, business leads see this as looking more so like a 70, 80, etc. and in their defense with no other data point available, that perspective isn't wrong.

HighCharts experts - please help me determine if some part of this API already covers this scenario or if a hand-rolled solution is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried to set the max value for the yAxis (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max)?

```
 yAxis: {
        max: 100
    }
```

like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zjwqfhe1/

vs with max value:

https://jsfiddle.net/x2mzt0hr/

Comment: you are welcome - so it was the right answer? so you could mark it as answer.